# Как правильно работать с 2-мерным массивом в <resources>?

Tags: android

Вопрос начального уровня изучения андроид. В активити есть 2-мерный массив такого формата:

```
String Data[][] = {  
{"text1", "text2", "text3"},  
{"text4", "text5", "text6"},  
{"text7", "text8", "text9"}  
}
```

Т.к. массив стал большым, появилась необходимость перенести его в ресурсы, для этого создаем string-array:

```
<resources> 
<string-array name="Data">  
<item> text1, text2, text3 </item>  
<item> text4, text5, text6 </item>  
<item> text7, text8, text9 </item>  
</string-array>
</resources>
```

Вопрос: Как правильно хранить и извлекать данные из этого массива? Насколько я понимаю, все что заключено в item воспринимается, как одна строка? Т.е. здесь нужно использовать `split()` для разделения каждой строки?

Comment: в общем то никак нельзя создать двумерный массив в ресурсах без костылей, вроде `split()`, но я бы не считал такое решение хоть сколько то приемлемым

Comment: @pavlofff а каким образом правильно хранить в приложении массивы string? Например, у меня массив в 1000 строк.

Comment: Можете ещё записать в файл и положить его в ресурсы приложения. В assets, например.

Comment: А они вам все 1000 нужны одновременно? Может пора подумать о SQLite? Вы дали слишком мало информации о проблеме, чтобы можно было дать корректный ответ.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja это игра-викторина, 1000 вопросов с 4 вариантами ответа, вопросы выбираются рандомно.

Comment: Я думаю лучше всего сделать через бд. Можно создать бд на ПК и при первом старте приложения она инициализируется. Вот тут написано, как это сделать https://software.intel.com/ru-ru/android/articles/using-a-database-with-your-android-app#_Toc382607353